# A thought experiment on escape velocity

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, thought-experiment, escape-velocity

Note: air resistance will be ignored for this thought experiment.

Suppose you hold a ball in your hands and have some kind of magical mechanism that allows you to begin accelerating upwards at a constant rate, away from the Earth's surface. Once your velocity passes escape velocity, let go of the ball. If I am correct, the ball should retain the velocity you were moving upwards with at the instant you let go of it. Since you were at moving above escape velocity, does the ball simply escape Earth's atmosphere, or does it somehow fall back to the ground?

If the ball falls to the ground, how did it lose its instantaneous velocity that you imparted on it after you let go?

If the ball does indeed escape, then I ask you to once again imagine the same situation, but this time, instead of dropping the ball when you pass escape velocity, you throw it downwards. Assuming the throw wasn't strong enough to cause the ball to move slower than escape velocity, does the ball still exit the atmosphere? How can the ball that was thrown 'down' still be moving 'up' relative to someone on the surface?

My current best guess about this situation is that the ball does indeed escape both when you drop it or throw it down. However, on an intuitive basis, I am still hesitant to fully commit to this guess. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, both of your thoughts are correct. The key is to be able to think in different frames of reference. In the case where you throw the ball down, it is moving down *relative to you*, but still moving up at a speed faster than escape velocity relative to the Earth's surface. Using the Galilean coordinate transformations (that is, neglecting the effects of special relativity) the ball's speed relative to the Earth is just $v_1-v_2$, where $v_1$ is your speed and $v_2$ is the speed at which you throw it down. But according to the way you set up your problem, $v_1-v_2>v_E$, where $v_E$ is escape velocity, so the ball will escape. And in the case where you just drop the ball, the setup is even simpler - the ball will no longer be subjected to the acceleration of the magical device, but it will still be moving fast enough to escape the gravitational well of the Earth.

It's worth noting that escape velocity doesn't mean the ball is no longer decelerated by gravity - as soon as you let go of the ball, it is losing speed continuously as the Earth attracts it. But escape velocity is simply defined as the velocity for which the ball will move completely free of the Earth's gravitational field before its velocity slows to $0$ and it is pulled back to the planet. So in both of the cases above, the ball will have enough speed to never return to Earth.

Comment: +1 but I don't think special relativity is relevant here. $v_e < 0.00004c \to \gamma(v_e) = 1$ to 10 decimal places - more than any plausible measurement precision is going to get you.

Comment: Sure, of course, I just thought I'd mention it.